# How can I get honesty in Succubox?

Tags: succubox

How can I get honesty in Succubox? I'm 100 levels and have 3242342342 of everything, yet I couldn't unlock honesty.

Answer (score 52):

If you click "Buy lootboxes with real money" and choose one of the payment options, a PayPal tab will open. Simply close that tab, and the game will ask you whether you really paid money. If you click "No", you will get honesty instead of loot boxes.

Comment: In my case, after the first playthrough and save reset, the option "Buy lootboxes with real money" (both as button and shop item) vanished permanently.

Answer (score 44):

I don't know the "honest" way of getting honesty, but you can just hit <kbd>f12</kbd> to bring up the console and type `data.honesty.value += x` where x is the number of honesty you would like to gain. If this results in you being put in prison due to your console being docked, you can just use `data.jailtimer = 1` to unjail yourself.

Comment: The irony of this solution is honestly amazing.

Comment: @Arperum No, it doesn't grant Irony:+1.

Comment: It *does* grant you Freedom +1 though.